# Did something just get broked with glibc/perl/irssi?

Tags: irssi, glibc

I was using irssi about 30 minutes ago now on Ubuntu server 12.04. Everything was perfectly fine and then all of the sudden something happened (my guess is a power failure). The box was restarted. When I logged back in and ran irssi, I got the following:

```
*** glibc detected *** irssi: double free or corruption (out): 0x0000000002085a40 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7e626)[0x7ffc01d87626]
irssi(config_node_set_str+0x98)[0x491768]
irssi[0x491f12]
irssi[0x491e61]
irssi(config_parse+0x52)[0x492112]
irssi[0x48ab81]
irssi(settings_init+0xd1)[0x48bf81]
irssi(core_init+0x79)[0x47a849]
irssi(main+0xd8)[0x4167e8]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xed)[0x7ffc01d2a76d]
irssi[0x416b41]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-004d0000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1319015                            /usr/bin/irssi
006cf000-006d0000 r--p 000cf000 08:01 1319015                            /usr/bin/irssi
006d0000-006dc000 rw-p 000d0000 08:01 1319015                            /usr/bin/irssi
006dc000-006dd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
02078000-02099000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7ffc0025b000-7ffc00270000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 655404                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7ffc00270000-7ffc0046f000 ---p 00015000 08:01 655404                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7ffc0046f000-7ffc00470000 r--p 00014000 08:01 655404                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7ffc00470000-7ffc00471000 rw-p 00015000 08:01 655404                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7ffc00471000-7ffc0073a000 r--p 00000000 08:01 1320172                    /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
7ffc0073a000-7ffc00746000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 655391                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.15.so
7ffc00746000-7ffc00945000 ---p 0000c000 08:01 655391                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.15.so
7ffc00945000-7ffc00946000 r--p 0000b000 08:01 655391                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.15.so
7ffc00946000-7ffc00947000 rw-p 0000c000 08:01 655391                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.15.so
7ffc00947000-7ffc00951000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 655392                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.15.so
7ffc00951000-7ffc00b51000 ---p 0000a000 08:01 655392                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.15.so
```

Followed by many more lines. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you can get this error if you have a syntax error in your `~/.irssi/config` file.

I was missing  a `"` in front of one of my lines, and adding that back fixed everything. I wouldn't have noticed a thing, if a friend hadn't asked a question.